# What will be the distribution of the expected marks?

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

in a multiple choice exam you have an unlimited supply of Questions,in Which a correct answer fetches 4 points a wrong answer a penalty of 1 mark.if you randomly select one of the four options available for each question, what is the number of questions you should try to make sure you are 99 percent sure to get marks above 20.

I tried to do this using the expected gain of each question(0.25) and got 80 which is wrong but I am unable to understand how to have a confidence interval of 99 percent on the expectation.Also what is the distribution which the expectation follows(is it normal by central limit theorem).

Comment: There's no reason not to use the exact (binomial) distribution unless you object to searching a bit.  If you want to speed things up, use the normal approximation.  You have the mean already (given you try $N$ questions), now you just need the variance.  Worth doing it both ways to test how reliable the approximation is.

Comment: Note:  but I'd start with the approximation, otherwise you'll waste a lot of time searching in the wrong places.

Comment: Also as a side comment, expectation is *not* associated with any confidence. It is a fixed, deterministic number. What you are looking for is the confidence interval of the values that the random variable takes, which is different from its expectation.

Comment: @lulu if possible can you provide me with a numerical answer my current answer using normal approximation deviates slightly from the original one

Comment: Please edit your post to include your answers.  As a quick guess:  did you use the continuity correction?  But, really, being off by one or two in a thing like this doesn't mean much.  It's not that precise a situation.

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong correction term.  With the standard continuity correction, I get $550$ which is not quite good enough (using the exact distribution).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of points you gain per answer (a random variable). Its distribution is

$$X \sim \begin{cases}4  &\text{ with probability } \frac{1}{4} \\ -1  &\text{ with probability } \frac{3}{4}\end{cases}$$

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be iid variables from this distribution (which are the points gained for each question).

We are interested in calculating $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \ge 20\right) \ge 0.99 \qquad (1)$$

Its useful to transform $X_i$'s into [Bernoulli distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) random variables. Note that

$$\frac{X+1}{5} \sim \begin{cases}1  &\text{ with probability } \frac{1}{4} \\ 0  &\text{ with probability } \frac{3}{4}\end{cases} = \text{Ber}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

So we can transform $(1)$ into

\begin{align}\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i+1) - N \ge 20\right) &\ge 0.99 \\ \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{X_i+1}{5} - \frac{N}{5} \ge 4\right) &\ge 0.99 \\ \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \text{Ber}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) - \frac{N}{5} \ge 4\right) &\ge 0.99 \\ \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \text{Ber}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \ge 4+\frac{N}{5}\right) &\ge 0.99 \\ \end{align}

The sum of iid Bernoulli random variables is a [Binomial random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\text{Binom}\left(N,\frac{1}{4}\right) \ge 4+\frac{N}{5}\right) &\ge 0.99 \\
\end{align}

Now we can use the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) to get a good approximation for $\text{Binom}\left(N,\frac{1}{4}\right)$, using Normal distribution. For this, we need to subtract the mean $\left(\frac{N}{5}\right)$ and divide by the variance $\left(\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}N=\frac{3}{16}N\right)$, then multiply by $\sqrt{N}$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\text{Binom}\left(N,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{N}{4} \ge 4+\frac{N}{5}-\frac{N}{4}\right) &\ge 0.99 \\
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\text{Binom}\left(N,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{N}{4}}{\frac{3}{16}N} \ge \frac{4-\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{3}{16}N}\right) &\ge 0.99 \\
\mathbb{P}\left(\sqrt{N}\frac{\text{Binom}\left(N,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{N}{4}}{\frac{3}{16}N} \ge \sqrt{N}\frac{4-\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{3}{16}N}\right) &\ge 0.99 \\
\end{align}

Now, due to the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), if $N$ is large, the left side is very closely approximated by a standard normal $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ variable. Since the expectation for $N$ you've calculated was $80$, this $N$ will likely be large enough for the approximation to be very close.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\mathcal{N}(0,1) \ge \sqrt{N}\frac{4-\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{3}{16}N}\right) &\ge 0.99 \\
\end{align}

The probability for a random variable to be $\ge$ to a value, is $1$ minus the probability of it being $<$:

\begin{align}
1-\mathbb{P}\left(\mathcal{N}(0,1) < \sqrt{N}\frac{4-\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{3}{16}N}\right) &\ge 0.99 \\
\end{align}

Now the $\mathbb{P}(...)$ section is just the $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution's CDF, $\phi$, evaluated at $\frac{4-\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{3}{16}N}$:

\begin{align}
1-\phi\left(\sqrt{N}\frac{4-\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{3}{16}N}\right) = 0.99 \\
0.01 = \phi\left(\sqrt{N}\frac{4-\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{3}{16}N}\right) \\
\phi^{-1}(0.01) = \sqrt{N}\frac{4-\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{3}{16}N} \\
\end{align}

Now we need to find the value of $\phi^{-1}(0.01)$, namely the $x$ where $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} dt \approx 0.01$. I did this numerically, and it turns out
$\phi(-3.723) \approx 0.01$, so $\phi^{-1}(0.01) \approx -3.723$.

\begin{align}
-3.723 &\approx \sqrt{N}\frac{4-\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{3}{16}N} \\
-3.723 \cdot \frac{3}{16}N &\approx \sqrt{N}\left(4-\frac{N}{20}\right) \\
-0.6980625N &\approx \sqrt{N}\left(\frac{80-N}{20}\right) \\
-13.9165N &\approx \sqrt{N}(80-N) \\
194.9165N^2 &\approx N(80-N)^2 \\
194.9165N &\approx (80-N)^2 \\
194.9165N &\approx 6400-160N+N^2 \\
0 &\approx 6400-354.9165N+N^2 \\
N_1 &\approx 19.0555;\quad N_2 \approx 354.915
\end{align}

When substituting back $N_1$ and $N_2$ into $-3.723 \approx \sqrt{N}\frac{4-\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{3}{16}N}$, we find that $N_1 = 19.0555$ does not satisfy the equation (we get $+3.723$ on the left side), but $N_2 = 354.915$ does.

So for the initial probability $(1)$ to be $\ge 0.99$, we need to answer at least $\boxed{N \ge 355}$ questions.

Comment: Not following.  If you attempt $74$ questions, you expect a score of $.25\times 74=18.5$  so you are suggesting that there is a $99\%$ chance that you will score significantly above the mean.

Comment: @lulu Yeah, you're right, $74$ did not seem right. So I checked what I did wrong, and it turns out, I had two mistakes: 1) In the Central Limit Theorem I forgot to multiply both sides by $\sqrt{N}$; 2) The Normal table I used was incorrect, so I calculated the integral with Python and corrected $\phi^{-1}(0.01)$, which is about $-3.723$, not $0.025$. Obviously any $\phi^{-1}(x), x < \frac{1}{2}$ would be negative, because the standard normal distribution is symmetrical, so I don't know how I could have trusted that $0.025$ value.

Comment: $355$ is still much too low.  The mean, for number of correct answers is $88.75$ and you need $75$ to get a score of $20$.  But $\sigma=\sqrt {355\times .25\times .75}\approx 8.16$ so getting below $75$ isn't even a $2\sigma$ event.  Certainly not a $99\%$ probability threshold.  I get $550$ if I use the approximation, closer to $560$ if I do it with the (exact) binomial

Comment: @lulu So what did I do wrong?

Comment: I haven't gone through your calculation, and of course it's possible that I too made a mistake though, as I say, the normal approximation and the exact binomial method yield very similar results.  Just back of envelope:  with $N=550$ we get a mean correct of $137.5$ and you need $114$ with $\sigma=10.155$ so that's a $2.3\sigma$ event.

Comment: The normal distribution decays very rapidly, so I think my estimate is realistic. I can't seem to find where I went wrong, I set up a Bernoulli random variable, the sum of which is Binomial. Then subtracted the mean, divided by the variance, and multiplied by $\sqrt{N}$, finally, I approximated the Binomial distribution with a Standard Normal distribution, and solved for $N$. So, to see who's right, I'd like to see your exact step-by-step calculations too.

Comment: So, do it with the binomial distribution.  It's easy enough.  With $N=355$ you want to claim that $\sum_{k=0}^{75}\binom {355}k\times .25^k\times .75^{355-k}≤.01$ but in reality it is $.05$ as we see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BBinomialCoefficient%5B355%2Ck%5D*.25%5Ek*.75%5E%28355-k%29%2C%7Bk%2C+1%2C+75%7D%5D)

Comment: @lulu Excuse my ignorance, but why are we adding to exactly $75$?

Comment: Note, I ought to have summed to $74$ in that expression (since you want the probability of getting *fewer* than $75$ to be $<.01$).  That doesn't change things much, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BBinomialCoefficient%5B355%2Ck%5D*.25%5Ek*.75%5E%28355-k%29%2C%7Bk%2C+1%2C+75%7D%5D).  However, that correction does make $550$ look good, scoring a victory for the normal approximation.  [Here for $550$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5BSum%5BBinomialCoefficient%5B550%2Ck%5D*.25%5Ek*.75%5E%28550-k%29%2C%7Bk%2C+1%2C+114%7D%5D%5D)

Comment: What does $74$ or $75$ have to do with the question?

Comment: Because that's what you need to get a score of $20$, given that you attempt $355$.  If you get $75$ correct then you get $355-75=280$ wrong which would give you a score of $4\times 75-280=20$.  My off by $1$ error, if that's what it is, arises from the fact that I think the OP wants $>20$.  If you insist on $>20$ then you actually need $76$ right.  This, of course, is a minor detail.

Comment: Okay, I understand your point now. I was just confused with all the numbers we were throwing around.

Comment: Well, I guess my answer is off by like $200$ somehow, but I don't know why. :(